# Collision laws (formulas) for colliding discs with rotation

Tags: mathematical-physics

Say you have two discs with fixed radii $r_{1}, r_{2}$, positions $q_{1}(t), q_{2}(t)$, momenta $p_{1}(t), p_{2}(t)$, which both depend on time $t$ and fixed masses $m_{1}, m_{2}$. They are assumed to move in a conservative force field, e.g. given by a Hamiltonian energy function, consisting of kinetic plus potential energy. The movement is constrained to a line and the two balls collide with each other elastically. That is, in a moment of collision (i.e. $q_{1} = q_{2}$) the momenta change according to

$$
p_{1}^{+} = \gamma p_{1}^{-} + (1+\gamma) p_{2}^{-},\\ 
p_{2}^{+} = (1 - \gamma) p_{1}^{-} - \gamma p_{2}^{-}
$$

with $\gamma = \frac{m_{1}-m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$, where $p_{i}^{-}$ is the momentum of the $i$-th ball right before collision and $p_{i}^{+}$ is the value of the momentum right after collision.

Assume now additionally, that both discs would rotate, that is, we give them some angular momentum expressed by rotating a radius vector $r_{i} = r_{i}(t)$ with respect to time. I want to know:

**1.** Would the elastic collision formula above change, if we assume the discs to be rotating?

**2.** How would the discs interchange rotation, i.e. which formula describes the passing from $r_{i}^{-}$ to $r_{i}^{+}$, in this case?

**3.** Do you know (examples) of elastic collision formulas that include both the momenta $p_{i}$ and the angular momenta $r_{i}$? (This depends of course on how you choose your energy, e.g. the Hamiltonian function).

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: As long as there isn't any external force acting(taking discs as a system) we can apply Linear momentum conservation.

Comment: The only external force is the potential energy $V(q)$. Take it, for instance, linear $V(q) = m_{1}q_{1} + m_{2}q_{2}$. Does Linear momentum conservation still apply then? 
I don't know what you mean by 'taking discs as a system'.

Comment: What are your own ideas about the answers to these questions?